# How to optimize latency in Spark Streaming job when reading data from Kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

**Problem description**

I want to speed up my streaming pipeline. So far the batch is being processed in ~10 seconds. Also in 2-3 months I expect x3 messages growth.

**Pipeline description**

I have Spark Streaming job that reads data from Kafka topic, process it (deserialize and enrich dataset) and writes the output into output topic.

**Kafka configuration**

- 1 topic
- 75 partitions per topic
- message generation frequency is 10 millions messages per minute (~165000 per second) in one partition
- message format is avro (under avro it's json event with 12-15 fields)

**Spark configuration**

- 75 executors (according to mapping recomendations - 1 Kafka partition to 1 Spark executor)
- trigger time - 1 minute

**What has already been done?**

- I requested to increase number of partitions in Kafka from 75 to 500 (it's impossible)
- I suggested to create a new topic with 500 partitions and setup replication from the current topic with 75 partitions to a new one (it's also impossible)
- I tried to play with message size (max.partition.fetch.bytes) - it didn’t help much, since Spark doesn’t care what is the message size if it can't parallelize the work properly

So I'm looking for a way to parallelize the work on Spark side. Any ideas what else can be done here?

Comment: AFAIK thats it Alex. may be you need to use the back pressure PID for production load

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can you repartition your  `InputDStream`?

Comment: @mazaneicha I tried that, to have 20, 100 and 1000 partitions acordingly. But it does not help much. Spark needs to shuffle data and thus latency is growing to 30-40 seconds for each batch.

Comment: Well, maybe some time in the future https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5997 :)  Although... 30 seconds to reshuffle ~75GB or so sounds like cluster might need some tuning.